# Can we differentiate two REST calls to the same endpoint by the same user in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I want to distinguish two API calls to the same endpoint by the same user? Is there any default way to do that in Spring Boot? As per my knowledge, each call is handled by a separate thread. So is there any way to get that thread ID for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you might be looking for Request Tracing where you can trace each request. To achieve the same you can use Zipkin and Sleuth.

Add the dependency in the pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

**ZipKin**

Internally it has 4 modules –

**Collector** – Once any component sends the trace data arrives to Zipkin collector daemon, it is validated, stored, and indexed for lookups by the Zipkin collector.

**Storage** – This module store and index the lookup data in backend. Cassandra, ElasticSearch and MySQL are supported.

**Search** – This module provides a simple JSON API for finding and retrieving traces stored in backend. The primary consumer of this API is the Web UI.

**Web UI** – A very nice UI interface for viewing traces.

---

**Sleuth**
Sleuth is a tool from Spring cloud family. It is used to generate the trace id, span id and add these information to the service calls in the headers and MDC, so that It can be used by tools like Zipkin and ELK etc. to store, index and process log files

---

Now you may see the logs as follow

```
2020-10-21 12:01:16.285  INFO [my-application,0b6aaf642574edd3,0b6aaf642574edd3,true] 289589 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] Example              : Hello world!
```

his entry corresponds to **`[application name,trace id, span id, whether the trace should be propagated to an external system]`**.

Comment: You may find more details here https://howtodoinjava.com/microservices/spring-cloud-zipkin-sleuth-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a means off the top of my head but, when working with Spring-Boot microservice architectures, I've typically added a correlation-id to the header or body that is then also returned with the response to provide an audit trail.

Of course, this assumes one is also responsible for the client making the API request, so apologies if this isn't the case for your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks much for your response. Exactly that is I was looking for a need to create an audit trail and assign an ID to it. I eventually put a Thread local variable and returned with the response. Since each request is handled by a separate thread, the problem solved.